# IIS logs before written to file

Tags: logging, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have an IIS version 8.5 web server running on Windows Server 2012 R2. Logging is configured on this server to write a new log file daily to `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`.

My "Log Event Destination" is set to `Log file only`, but clearly, if the logs are only being written once a day, the contents of today's log file is being cached somewhere prior to being dumped to disk. Where is this cache held, and can I access it so that I can read events logged today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each log is created a 0 hours UTC time, and added to as the day and activity progresses, probably with some memory caching. You will see any given days log file long before that day ends.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Craig's answer you should know that it's possible to immediately flush the most recent log entries to disk with the following command;

```
netsh http flush logbuffer
```

Without this the logs will flush automatically every minute or 64KB.

See this entry on Scott Forsyth's blog;

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/flush-http-and-ftp-logs-in-iis